# Reversed modal transition in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, transition

I need to make reversed modal transition and how to make it? I dont know anything about making custom transitions and I will be happy if someone will help me with my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by reversed modal transition?

Comment: modal transition is from bottom to top and i need transition from top to bottom

Comment: I'd love to hear about your findings